# How Do I code this in python with simplejson

Tags: python, json

how do i code a python program that return a  json element that look like this

```
{1:{'name':foo,'age':xl}
  2:{'name':vee,'age':xx}
  ....
}
```

What i meant is that i want return nested dictionaries

What i hoped to accomplish is  something like this

```
var foo = 1.name  # to the the value of name in the clientside
```

I hope all this made sense .English is my second language

thanks in advance

Comment: In both Python and JavaScript (and by extension, JSON), numbers are not valid dictionary/object keys. You'll want to put those in quotes. However, you still won't be able to access children as `obj.1.name`—you'll need to use something along the lines of `obj["1"].name`, as `1` cannot be a variable name.

Comment: alright thanks i think i finally got it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import simplejson as json 
    # "simplejson" works exactly the same as with "json"
>>> json.dumps({})
'{}'
>>> json.dumps({'asdf':1,'poi':[2,3,4,{'qwer':5}]})
'{"asdf": 1, "poi": [2, 3, 4, {"qwer": 5}]}'
>>>
```

Comment: voyager thanks you have to break down your answer for me please. i want asdf for example to be increase down the line.You know 1,2,3 ....